# How To Get Data From Arduino Uno Onto My Laptop Through The USB

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, usb, ubuntu

I want to write a c++ program that does something with the data from one of the input analog pins as the program runs, but I want to know how to get the value from the arduino uno though the USB port (that I am also using to power the uno) and into my laptop for using. IS there any documentation I should read?

My laptop runs Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.

EDIT: I am not talking about the Serial monitor by the way

Comment: Chech the "serial" scetch and open "serial monitor" in the ArduinoIDE. You can write a program that reads data from the serial.

Comment: Check out the inbuilt examples. There are many options there. How do you plan to store the data on your computer once it gets there?

Answer (score 1):

The "Serial Monitor" is merely a window to the Arduino's serial port. You don't have to use it to use Serial. It's just a (very simple) built in way of seeing the data.

You can use the Serial interface with your own software, or with third party software. It's not tied to the Serial Monitor in any way at all.

So:

- Use `Serial.print()` etc to send data to the PC
- Write your own PC software in your language of choice to process that data, or
- Use some third party application to read and process the serial data